# OpenWRT - RTSP doesn’t work on 802.11b (no video stream, but audio works)

Tags: networking, wifi, routing, video, openwrt

I have an issue with configuring OpenWRT on MT7628 chip from Mediatek.

OpenWRT version: 19.07.3

Expected behavior: OpenWRT creates a local Wi-Fi network (no connection to the global internet). Two devices connect to the OpenWRT Wi-Fi. One of the devices creates RTSP stream, the other receives this stream. (Example - RTSP camera and user's phone watching the video feed). The stream on the camera is configured for maximum bitrate of 1mbps.

Issue: When 802.11b is forced, the RTSP video stream cannot be viewed, however, the audio (although extremely patchy and laggy) is working. When set to 802.11n, the stream works, but is very patchy and full of artifacts.

Diagnostics done so far: I'm almost certain it's not hardware performance issue, because the same scenario works flawlessly on an off-the-shelf "wall-plug-type" AP with proprietary firmware and the MT7628 chip. However, on my VoCore2 board with the same chip and OpenWRT the issue persists